# trouble using string.replace with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given something a regex like  this:

http://rubular.com/r/ai1LFT5jvK

I want to use string.replace to replace "subdir" with a string of my choosing.

Doing  `myStr.replace(/^.*\/\/.*\.net\/.*\/(.*)\/.*\z/,otherStr)`

only returns the same string, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/nLmbV/

If you view the Rublar, it appears to capture what I want it to capture, but on the Fiddle, it doesn't replace it.

I'd like to know why this happens, and what I'm doing wrong. A correct regex or a correct implementation of the `replace` call would be nice, but most of all, I want to understand what I'm doing wrong so that I can avoid it in the future.

### EDIT

I've updated the fiddle to change my regex from:

```
/^.*\/\/.*\.net\/.*\/(.*)\/.*\z/
```

to

```
 /^.*\/\/.*\.net\/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/
```

And according to the fiddle, it just returns `hello` instead of `https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/dir/hello/Slide1_v2.PNG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that little `\z` in your regex.

You probably forgot to replace it with a `$` sign. JavaScript uses `^` and `$` as anchors, while Ruby uses `\A` and `\z`.

---

To answer your edit:

The match is always replaced as a whole. You'll want to group both the left side and the right side of the to-be-replaced part and reinsert it in the replacement:

```
url.replace(/^(.*\/\/.*\.net\/.*\/).*(\/.*)$/,"$1hello$2")
```

Comment: oh. Welp. Yep. That would explain it.
I just like the black background of Rublar. The javascript regex testers I've seen all have white backgrounds...

Comment: just about to answer. you new regex: `/^.*\/\/.*\.net\/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/`

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian Upon replacing the characters, this new regex combined with `string.replace` doesn't seem to return what I expect it to return. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Before I get marked down, I know the question asks about regexp. The reason for this answer URLs are nearly impossible to process reliably with a regexp without writing fiendishly complex regexps. It can be done, but it makes your head hurt!
If you are doing this in a browser, you can use an A tag in your script to make things much simpler. The A tag knows how to parse them into pieces, and it lets you modify the pieces independently, so you only need to deal with the pathname:

```
//make a temporary a tag
var a = document.createElement('a');
//set the href property to the url you want to process
a.href = "scheme://host.domain/path/to/the/file?querystring"
//grab the path part of the url, and chop up into an array of directories
var dirs = a.pathname.split('/');
//set 2nd dir name - array is ['','path','to','file']
dirs[2]='hello';
//put the path back together
a.pathname = dirs.join('/');
```

a.href now contains the URL you want.
More lines, but also more hair left when you come back to change the code later.

Comment: I've already had to change some of my regexes once because the url structure changed. I might just do this in the future.